# Headless chrome in python - configuration options

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium, headless

When I run headless chrome I'm using these options

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1080,1920")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

Recently the console has output the following error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60552/devtools/browser/4082a43a-e17a-4002-8b21-5ba10473a0f6
[0501/182125.387:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
```

The script still runs without error, but to keep things tidy I'd like to ask here as my Google searches haven't amounted to much. I was hoping `disable-gpu` would've solved it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No I just ended up living with it..